# How can I invert the colors of images in bulk by Imagemagick?

Tags: colors, imagemagick, figure, mogrify

I would like to invert the colour of numerous figures in a fold in Linux, the code is as follows:

```
mogrify /home/yu/Desktop/1 -negate /home/yu/Desktop/2
```

The origin file is in path 1, and the target fold is path 2.

However, it's wrong. It points out that "*mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562*."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the `-path` parameter for "/home/yu/Desktop/2`, and a file pattern -- not just the parent directory.

```
mogrify -path /home/yu/Desktop/2 -negate /home/yu/Desktop/1/*.jpg
```

Be sure to replace `*.jpg` with whatever file type you are expecting in the source directory.

> [image: remember] Remember to define all CLI arguments before the filename pattern when using the `mogrify` utility.